# How to Install Jenkins using Apache Brooklyn and Chef

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, jclouds, brooklyn

I want to install Jenkins on a VM using Chef (and Apache Brooklyn). The blueprint being used is,

```
name: chef-jenkins
location:
  jclouds:aws-ec2:
    region: xyz
services:
- type: chef:jenkins
  cookbook_urls:
    jenkins: .../jenkins.tgz
    runit:  ... /runit.tgz
    apt:     .../apt.tgz
    yum:     .../yum20150407-59421-1bw7bou.tar.gz
  launch_run_list: [ "jenkins::start" ]
  service_name: jenkinsd
```

The `service_name` parameter is incorrect.

Running this throws an error `"Failure running task ssh: run chef for launch (jSUGhBph): SSH task ended with exit code 1 when 0 was required, in Task[ssh: run chef for launch:jSUGhBph]: run chef for launch"`.

What else am I missing? Is it possible to run a simple chef recipe (e.g. https://gist.github.com/nstielau/978920) directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you saw indicates that one of the shell commands that Brooklyn tried to run on the cloud server failed - in particular to "run chef for launch" command. To find out why this failed, use the *Activity* tab:

1. The tree view on the left contains the whole application. Expand this.
2. This will reveal the entities that make up the application. This blueprint has only one, called `jenkins (chef)` - click on this.
3. Click on the *Activity* tab. This will show you the list of tasks. One of them will have the status *Failed* - click on this.
4. Tasks can have subtasks, so you may see another task list, with one in status *Failed* - keep following this trail until you come to the last failed task
5. If this is an SSH task, you will have links to download `stdout` and `stderr` - you can inspect these to find out exactly why the shell command failed.

You can also find a [section on troubleshooting in the Apache Brooklyn user guide](http://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/latest/ops/troubleshooting/index.html) which may help diagnose other problems.

I've taken your blueprint and made a few modifications; this is now working on my Ubuntu 14.04 image:

```
name: chef-jenkins
location: vagrant-trusty
services:
- type: chef:jenkins
  cookbook_urls:
    jenkins: data:application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8;base64,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
    apt:     https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/apt/archive/v2.7.0.tar.gz
    java:    https://github.com/agileorbit-cookbooks/java/archive/v1.29.0.tar.gz
  launch_run_list: [ "jenkins::default" ]
  service_name: jenkins
  launch_attributes:
    java:
      jdk_version: 7
```

This blueprint is ready-to-run (except for changing the location to match your requirements). Here are some of the changes I have made:

- Full URLs for the three cookbooks
- The `jenkins` data URL contains a bare-bones cookbook containing the [recipe you referred to in a gist](https://gist.github.com/nstielau/978920), tarred-and-gzipped
- For the jenkins cookbook, I had to specify `depends "apt"` and `depends "java"` in `metadata.rb` otherwise I got strange Chef errors
- Fixed `launch_run_list` to refer to the correct recipe name
- Fixed `service_name` to refer to the correct service name
- Added `launch_attributes` to configure the Java cookbook to install Java 7 (the default of Java 6 is not supported by Jenkins)